# Django why can't I authenticate a user?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a user authentification form using Django +1.8 but I encountered a problem, when I press the form submit button, nothing happens, the page is just reloading instead of loging in, why?

Here is the code:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout

# Create your views here.
def user(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'user.html', context)

def login(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user is not None:
                auth_login(request, user)
            else:
                context['error'] = 'Non active user'
        else:
            context['error'] = 'Mauvais nom d\'utilisateur ou mot de passe'
    else:
        context['error'] = ''
    return render(request, 'user.html', context)

def logout(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        auth_logout(request)
    else:
        context['error'] = 'une erreur s\'est produite.'
    return render(request, 'user.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from utilisateur import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.user, name="user"),
        url(r'^login$', views.login, name='login'),
        url(r'^logout$', views.logout, name='logout'),
    ]
```

**user.html**

```
{% block content %}
{% if user.authenticated %}
<p>{{ user.username }}</p>
<a href="logout?">Logout</a>
{% else %}
<form method="post" action="login">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>username:<input type="text" name="username"></p>
    <p>password:<input type="password" name="password"></p>
    <input value="Se connecter" type="submit">
</form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I also thought that the middlewares could be useful in order to solve this issue.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

'context_processors': [
     'django.template.context_processors.debug',
     'django.template.context_processors.request',
     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
],
```

I think the problem comes from `context_instance=RequestContext(request)`, how can I solve this ?

Comment: Wow.. you are using GET for login? It means your username, and password would be exposed in cleartext. Use POST instead

Comment: @karthikr Thanks for the advice, I still have troubles with GET and POST.

Comment: Think of it like this (for the most part): `GET` is used when you want to *retrieve* information, and `POST` is used when you want to *alter* information.

Comment: @Hybrid Okay, but why can't I authenticate?

Comment: There are a few more issues. Edit the question with your changed code.

Comment: @karthikr The problem is still the same, but I edited GET as POST

Comment: Then why is this still get `<form method="get" action="login">` ? Also, it should not be `try..except` - You should do: `if request.method == "POST":`

Comment: why are you using context_instance? Why are you using "GET" method instead of "POST" for login? (It's vulnerable). In templates replace "authenticated" to "user.is_authenticated". I recommend you to read this tutorial http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/login.html (works even in 1.8 version).

Comment: @karthikr I updated it and changed the bad parts, the problem is still persisting.

Comment: Are you sure it is a problem? What makes you think the code is not running correctly? You just re-render the same html after logging the user in.

Comment: @karthikr I know it is working, but I don't know why it isn't rendering my username as if I was logged in `{% if user.authenticated %}
<p>{{ user.username }}</p> {% else %} ...`, this is the thing I want to fix.

Comment: Try request.user.username instead

Comment: @karthikr doesn't work, the code is taking the `{% else %}` part but ignoring the `{% if user.authenticated %}` (I tried `authenticated`, `user.authenticated`, `request.user.authenticated` but still nothing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually authentication is working properly. All you need to make some corrections like, **user.authemticated** to **user.is_authenticated** and change the logout function and url on template

user.html:

```
{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p>{{ user.username }}</p>

<a href="/logout">Logout</a>
{% else %}
<form method="post" action="login">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>username:<input type="text" name="username"></p>
    <p>password:<input type="password" name="password"></p>
    <input value="Se connecter" type="submit">
</form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout

# Create your views here.
def user(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'user.html', context)

def login(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                auth_login(request, user)
            else:
                context['error'] = 'Non active user'
        else:
            context['error'] = 'Mauvais nom d\'utilisateur ou mot de passe'
    else:
        context['error'] = ''
    return render(request, 'user.html', context)

def logout(request):
    context = {}
    auth_logout(request)
    return render(request, 'user.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you just forgot to add a line to redirect the user to another page if the user is valid after authentication. You should replace these lines

```
`if user is not None:
    if user is not None:
       auth_login(request, user)
    else:
       context['error'] = 'Non active user'
 else:
    context['error'] = 'Mauvais nom d\'utilisateur ou mot de passe'`
```

with these

```
if user is not None:
    auth_login(request, user)
    redirect('login')
 else:
    context['error'] = 'Mauvais nom d\'utilisateur ou mot de passe'
```

then you go ahead and if the user has been authenticated with your template with this

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

or

```
{% if not user.is_anonymous %}
```

feel free to let me know if the problem still persists